# Find the array status after k turns

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm

> Code Chef Problem
>
> Given array of **N** integers **A** and a number **K**. During a turn the maximal value over all Ai is chosen, let's call it **MAX**. Then **Ai =
>   MAX - Ai** is done for every **1 <= i <= N**. Find out how will the array look like after K turns.
>
> **Input**
>
> The numbers **N** and **K** are given in the first line of an input. Then **N** integers are given in the second line which denote the array **A**.
>
> **Output**
>
> Output **N** numbers on a single line. It should be the array **A** after **K** turns.
>
> **Constraints**
>
> ```
> 1 <= N <= 10^5
> 0 <= K <= 10^9
> ```
>
> **Ai** does not exceed 2 * 10^9 by it's absolute value.
>
> Example
>
> Input:
>
> ```
> 4 1
> 5 -1 7 0
> ```
>
> Output:
>
> ```
> 2 8 0 7
> ```

Here is my code. It works perfectly fine in my local computer (Dec C++ 5.5.1 OS Win8). I have been thinking over this for the last 2 days but when I upload it on code chef it shows **wrong answer**. Please tell me what am I missing in this code ?

```
#include <stdio.h>

long long int find_largest(long long int A[], long size){
    long int largest =A[0],i;

    for(i=1;i<size;i++){
        if(largest < A[i])
            largest = A[i];
    }
    return largest;
}
int main(){
    long long int A[100000],K,j,largest =0, temp,prev_largest = 0;
    long N, i;                          
    char eof_chk;
    int flag = 0;

while(1){
    scanf("%ld %lld",&N,&K);
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        scanf("%lld",&A[i]);
    largest = find_largest(A,N);
    // Processing...
    for(j=1; j<=K; j++){
        largest = find_largest(A,N);
        if(prev_largest == largest){
            if((K-j)%2 == 0){
                for ( i = 0; i < N; i++ ){
                    temp = largest - A[i];  
                    if(temp > 2000000000)
                        A[i] = -(2000000000 - temp + 2000000000 + 1);
                    else
                        A[i] = temp;
                }
                break;
            }
            else break;
        }
        else{
            for ( i = 0; i < N; i++ ){
                temp = largest - A[i];  
                if(temp > 2000000000)
                    A[i] = -(2000000000 - temp + 2000000000 + 1);
                else
                    A[i] = temp;
            }
            prev_largest = largest;
        }       
    }
    // Start for formated printing
    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        if(i == (N-1)){
            printf("%lld",A[i]);    
        }           
        else
            printf("%lld ",A[i]);
    }
    // End for formated printing
    if(getchar() == EOF) {
        break;
    }
    else
        printf("\n");
}   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What you should be doing is finding testcases where your code doesn't work. Try boundary conditions (very large/very small cases). Then use a debugger to trace the error through your code. (Also compile with full warnings and address anything the compiler tells you about.)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Indeed I tried with all possible test cases. But I think the problem is how we handle the overflow. Because in the question it is mentioned that the **Array elements** _does not_ exceed 2*10^9. So could you please tell me how to handle the overflow if the difference of MAX and Ai exceeds 2*10^9. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user3243499: What is the `sizeof(long long)` for your compiler?

Comment: @MartinR It is 8 bytes

Comment: @user3243499: Then it can hold values up to 9223372036854775807 which is much more than you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem description

- http://www.codechef.com/MAY14/problems/RRSTONE

states only that the *initial* array values are in the range
`-2*10^9 .. 2*10^9`, but not that you should restrict the values to this range after each iteration step. So your "main processing loop" should simply look like this:

```
for(j=1; j<=K; j++){
    largest = find_largest(A,N);
    for ( i = 0; i < N; i++ ) {
        A[i] = largest - A[i]; 
    }
}
```

Then

- The initial array values are in the range `-2*10^9 .. 2*10^9`.
- After the first iteration all array values are in the range `0 .. 4*10^9`.
- In all following iterations, the array values stay in the range `0 .. 4*10^9`.

`long long int` is an 64-bit quantity on your compiler and can hold values up to
`9223372036854775807`. That is sufficient for all these calculations.

Comment: Thanks. I did the same thing in the beginning but I they didnot accept my code. Showing " Wrong Answer ". I don't know if its code chef parsing error or with my code. But thanks for your reply.

Comment: Thanks a lot. +100 for the "long long int is an 64-bit quantity on your compiler and can hold values up to 9223372036854775807". My code is now accepted. Thanks again.

Comment: I am having a same problem.. Wrong Answer. Can you help me with it.. my main function :  `long n;`
 cin>>n;
 long long int k,j,largest;
 cin>>k;
 vector<long long int> inputArray(n);
 for(long i=0;i<n;i++)
 {
  cin>>inputArray[i];
 }
 
 for(j=1; j<=k; j++){
    largest = find_largest(inputArray,n);
    for (long i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
        inputArray[i] = largest - inputArray[i]; 
    }
 
 for(long i=0;i<n;i++)
 {
  cout<<inputArray[i];
  if(i!=n-1)
  cout<<" ";
 }
 cout<<endl;
 return 0; </code>